# No logro vincular CSS al HTML

Tags: html, css

Estoy comenzando a aprender y se me dificulta vincular el CSS, ya vi un monton de videos, aparentemente se encuentra vinculada correctamente pero los cambios en mi pág de CSS no impactan. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo creadas las respectivas carpetas bien y si presiono sobre href incluso me redirecciona a la ventana, sin embargo los cambios siguen sin impactar. Probé poniendo algo simple para verificar que esté ingresando todo correcto y en el código de CSS tampoco hay errores [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quizás te faltan las medidas... `width: 70`... pero `70` que? quizas quisiste decir `70px`? `70%`? quizás si te está aplicando el estilo, pero si no le pones unidad de medida, el navegador no sabe que hacer.

Comment: Podria darse el caso de un problema de cache de tu navegador, por lo tanto, cuando hagas cambios en el CSS, pulsa sobre el botón "Refrescar" (ese que aparece al lado izquierdo de la barra de URL de tu navegador) mientras estes pulsando la tecla Shift (mayúsculas) de la izquierda de tu teclado, y eso fuerza una actualización de la cache y deberías poder ver tus ultimos cambios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegurate que la url del CSS es la correcta, usa una dirección desde la raiz del servidor /assets/css/styles.css
Comprueba que el css está en ese lugar dirige el navegador a
https://tusitio.com/assets/css/style.css
Debe aparecer el archivo de estilo.
Y para asegurarte que se leen los cambios debes desconectar la cache. Ve a la herramientas de desarrollador (F12 o mediante el menu del navegador), ahí buscas en la pestaña red **Inhabilitar cache**.
Chrome además te da la opción de forzar la recarga sin cache: botón derecho del ratón en el icono de cargar página de nuevo, verás la opción de forzar recarga completa.

Comment: mmm... no sabia lo del botón derecho en ese icono, y en mi caso, desde Ubuntu con Chrome, no me aparece ningún menu contextual ni nada :-(  (¿no será alguna extensión que lo haga o algo así?... yo no uso ninguna ni he tocado nunca su configuración, vamos, esta todo por defecto)

Comment: El menú contextual en el botón recarga de Chrome aparece mientras tengas abierto el panel del inspector de código.  Lo mismo que deshabilitar la cache, que solo actua con las herramientas de desarrollador abierta.

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo veo, gracias por aclarármelo :-)  (aún así me gusta mas el truco del (Shift + Boton recarga) pues es comun a Chrome  Firefox (y seguramente más).

Comment: Recién veo que me había olvidado de responder. Me sirvió un montón tu consejo. Gracias!!!

Comment: @Abril Si esta respuesta es la que te ha servido deberías marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa. Así funciona este sitio. Los agradecimientos están bien, pero si además aceptas la respuesta, se sobreentiende que te ha servido y es lo que en tu caso ha funcionado bien.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes tu style.css en la misma carpeta que tu pagina, no es necesario que coloques toda la ruta de carpetas. Solo podrias hacer referencia como: style.css y como te dijeron en comentarios anteriores:
colocale al width: 70px; o 70%;.

podrias tratar de poner en tu página principal html:

```
<body> este es una prueba </body>
```

y en el style.css:

```
body{
      align-items: center;
}
```

y revisar en la página si se aplica el style, si tienes duda del navegador por la cache, intenta abrir la pagina web en otro navegador distinto.

Comment: Recién veo que me había olvidado de responder. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda! Me sirvió de mucho